# How to add new fonts to gimp?

Tags: libreoffice, fonts, gimp

With this question I refer to the one, where to add fonts to libreoffice :

[Why I can't install new fonts in LibreOffice?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191200/why-i-cant-install-new-fonts-in-libreoffice)

How can I add new fonts to gimp ?

Comment: This means, that the solution for LibreOffice like above is globally working in space of $user ?! Once done - then gimp use the new fonts too ?! - have to look after ... - true ! super !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you install your fonts to the `.fonts` folder, they will be available for all programs from within your user's session.

For the GIMP specifically, you can also check the Preferences from the menu **Edit > Preferences**, then **Folders | Fonts** (see image, below). There you can find out where GIMP's own fonts folder is and add/manage additional font folders.

So, if you want some specific fonts to be available *exclusively* to GIMP, you would copy the font files to GIMP's font folder.

If you want GIMP to be able to use fonts in your system that are not available system-wide (e.g., installed by TeXLive or other programs in their own folders), you add the corresponding font folder.

[image: Fonts folders for the GIMP]

<sup>Click on the image for a full-resolution version.</sup>

**Note**: It is *not* necessary to add the `.fonts` folder to the GIMP Preferences.

Answer (score 6):

You have to add the fonts that you want to Ubuntu first, and then it will be available to Gimp, and other apps as well.

Download the font that you want, and use Font viewer to install it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case the solution was move the folder with tff files inside to `/usr/share/fonts/truetype` folder, in spite of that this path are not setted in typography folder in gimp settings, but works! :)